# Dismissable PageControl At Launch

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to create an instruction screen for an app, but this is my first run in with PageControls.

What's the best way for me to show a UIScrollView with PageControl that'll show the user a bunch of images but dismiss the PageControl when the user gets to the end of the images?

Answer (score 0):

Use the storyboard and make your helpscreen the initial viewcontroller. Use `NSTimer` to change the displayed image. Let the last timer event trigger your segue to the next view controller (via `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`)

Hint: allow the user to cancel the sequence and jump directly to the first "real" view.